# Can I retrieve comments for all objects on a domain?

Tags: dns, comments, facebook-fql

I have domain with 36 thousand photos in it. I want to see lastest comments. I'm very lazy to check every page, so I tried

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time 
 FROM comment 
 WHERE object_id IN 
  (SELECT comments_fbid 
   FROM link_stat 
   WHERE url like 'http://fotograf.web.tr')
```

Take a closer look to last line. There is **like**,  fql dont accept **like**.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203158/how-to-list-all-comments-in-my-domain

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you already have a list of pages on your domain, why not put those in an 'IN' clause in the query?