# how to get all facebook comments for a domain?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

For example I use Facebook comment for my website like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN2nF.jpg

Couple post has Facebook comments area comments too.

Now I wanna display recent 10 Facebook comments on on my sidebar ?

How can I do it ?

is that possible ?

the example with commented post:

http://fatihtoprak.com/usb-disk-flash-ten-format-atmak.html

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203158/how-to-list-all-comments-in-my-domain

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Ostermiller