# Retrieve ALL Facebook Comments for website/App ID Using Graph API (i.e. get latest comments)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I'm trying to create a feed of latest comments for a website. I don't have any problem getting comments on a per post basis but I don't seem to be able to find any way to get **all**, or at least the last 10 comments for the entire website.

Obviously I'd like to do this in the simplest way possible and I figured this would be via the Graph API.

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to get the comments from? A page/group? Or a specific user?

Comment: I have the FB comments plugin on lots of different pages on a website. I know how to get the comments for each page, but I want to have a latest comments list on the home page (for ALL comments on ALL pages)

Comment: Can you link us the blog software and the specific comments tool you're using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203158/how-to-list-all-comments-in-my-domain

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to enter all the URLs, but it can be done via FQL using the comments and link_stat table.

```
SELECT xid, text, username, time
FROM comment
WHERE
object_id IN
(SELECT comments_fbid FROM link_stat WHERE url IN (All_your_URLs))
```

Can you try the above and see if it works ?

Reference - [Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/) & [Link_Stat](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)

Comment: I think there are going to be too many URLs. There are currently 1,500 and more coming

Comment: I feared as much..how about the comment moderation tool - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments ? This interface will be available to you if you have added the application-id meta tag to your pages. More info on the Comments plugin page.

Comment: I have the comment moderation tool set up and that's pretty much what I want to pull on to the website. Do you know if there is there any way I can do that?