# OAuthException "An unexpected error has occurred" when trying to query count field of comments_info table with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-apps, facebook-comments

We have a Facebook app that uses the FB comments social plugin. We're trying to automatically pull the total number of comments that have been posted using that app.

We've tried using this query:

```
SELECT count FROM comments_info WHERE app_id = 210218945658186
```

However, this returns the following information:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2
  }
}
```

If we query fields other than the count field, the result is properly returned. This query:

```
SELECT xid, app_id, updated_time FROM comments_info WHERE app_id = 210218945658186
```

Returns the following results:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "xid": null,
      "app_id": 210218945658186,
      "updated_time": 1315413930
    }
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know how we could fix the unexpected error? We've tried this query several times over the past few days, so it's not an intermittent issue. We tried the solution at http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9708969/event-query-using-fql-returns-oauthexception-an-unknown-error-has-occurred using columns from the comments_info table, but that didn't work.

We've also looked at other options to total the number of comments in the app. The answer at [How to list all comments in my domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203158/how-to-list-all-comments-in-my-domain/10412716#10412716) doesn't work because we have a variable number of subpages the comments plugin is used on.